# Как изменить версию .NET Framework в Visual Studio? (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Только начинаю изучать `С#`.

Установил `Visual Studio 2022`. Создаю консольное приложение и не могу установить другую версию `.NET Framework`.

В выпадающем окошке доступна только 6 версия.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Большинство же туториалов ориентированы на версии `4 - 4.5`.

Как изменить версию `.NET`?

Буду рад любой помощи!

Comment: .NET Framework является устаревшим, его не стоит вообще использовать сейчас если на то нет прям очень весомой необходимости (WinXP например с его .NET FW 4). Не, ну если хотите, то смотрите внимательно проект, который выбираете в студии, их там 2 (`Консольное приложение` и `Консольное приложение (.NET Framework)`), а так, сидите на .NET6, материал с туториалов под старые версии спокойно будет применим и к новым версиям фреймворка.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение, все работает! По поводу устаревшей версии .net -а учтую

Comment: Весь код старого шарпа без проблем будет работать в новом. На уровне обучающих примеров разницы нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Во-первых**, `.NET 6` и `.NET Framework 4.5` это хоть и разные платформы, но думаю для начала освоения подойдут и туториалы для `.NET Framework`. У вас на скриншоте `.NET 6` (бывший `.NET Core`). Главное их различие это наличие кроссплаформенности у `.NET` (`.NET Framework работает только на Windows`), более подробно про различия можете почитать [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/architecture/modernize-desktop/whats-new-dotnet).

**Во-вторых**, касательно вашего вопроса, вам нужно использовать **Visual Studio Installer**, можете либо найти и запустить его как отдельное приложение, либо в меню выбора типа проекта должна быть кнопка его запуска. Запустив его выберите нужную вам платформу, установите её и перезапустите **Visual Studio**.

Comment: "но думаю для начала освоения подойдут и туториалы для .NET Framework" - вы очень ошибаетесь. Эта ошибка приведет к тому, что человек отстанет на 3 года от материала, который и так обновляется каждые полгода (!), конечно циклы/условия/методы - да, можно и на .NET Framework изучить (можно и на паскале так-то), но какой смысл учить старьё которое умерло, когда есть новое и свежее? Многие фичи из .NET Framework попросту не реализованы в .NET

Comment: @Kalmankantaja Я имел ввиду начальный уровень (как раз циклы/условия/методы).